# Javascript error while adding a row to a dojo datagrid

Tags: javascript, datagrid, dojo

I am getting a javascript error **newItem() was not passed an identity for the new item.**
while i am adding a new row to a dojo datagrid.When does this error occur and for what reasons? Please guide.
Please find the below code i have written to add a new row to a datagrid.

```
function add(){ 
 var value = 1000;
if (value ==1000) {
    value = dataGrid.rowCount;
    dataGrid.edit.apply();
}
value=value+1;
gridStore.newItem(dojo.mixin( {
    id:value,
    name:'',
    place:'',
    state:'',
    country:''
}));
try {
} catch (e) {
    alert("Please try again...");
}
```

}//end of function

Answer (score 0):

Using `Numbers` for identifiers is not a good idea.  Try casting the `value` to a string when creating a new item

```
gridStore.newItem(dojo.mixin( {
    id:value + "",
    name:'',
    place:'',
    state:'',
    country:''
}));
```